# More link - not text

Tags: functions, excerpt

I am using origin theme. This theme writes dots in post end. In functions.php file I saw line with text:

```
function origin_excerpt_more( $more ) { 
    return '...';
```

I changed text to **More...** and instead of dots text changed. I want that text **More...** change to link **More...** And link would be to the post.

How do I change this code? My website is [popietevirtuveje.lt](http://popietevirtuveje.lt)

Comment: Please add a link to the theme’s source code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code;

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return ' <div id="daha"><a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read More</a></div>';
```

}

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: It doesn't work.